# ISessionFactory implementation

Tags: nhibernate

I want to create a custom implementation to ISessionFactory.  I'm only interested in override the OpenSession method, thus I want to inherit of the base class actually implementing ISessionFactory, but I don't find it.  Someone knows what class is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its implemented in [SessionFactoryImpl](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionFactoryImpl.cs) but what exactly is it you want to do in OpenSession, nhibernate has lots of extensions points maybe there is a simpler way to accomplist what you are trying to do.

Comment: I simply want to attach a opened connection object instead to create a new one in each OpenSession.  This is for tests purposes with SQLite, whereas the in memory database is gone when the connection closes.

Comment: As far as i remember you can supply your own connection to OenSession? Otherwise you probably want to look at the ConnectionFactory instead of the SessionFactory

Comment: OK, SessionFactoryImpl is a sealed class, thus I can't use for my purpose.  Off the record, wich is the point of create a interface of a sealed class?  The developer is expecting an all or nothing implementation?

Comment: Did you look at using connectionprovider or simlilar, and isn't it enough to pass the opened connection to OpenSession?

Comment: I ended to stick to SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession in order to mantain a reference to an opened connection.